# Node.js Sentry error caputuring not working

Tags: node.js, sentry

In Node.js 8 I'm not able to capture error on sentry if I am using process.exit(0) at the end of my code. Otherwise its working fine

```
const Sentry = require('@sentry/node');
Sentry.init({ dsn: 'https://c3f5****************34dbf@sentry.io/1288850' });
try{
    throw new Error('test-error');
}
catch(e){
    const Eid = Sentry.captureException(e);
    console.log(Eid);
}
process.exit(0);
```

Comment: make it async function.

Answer (score 5):

Sentry.captureException(e) is asynchronous, so process.exit(0) is terminating the process before Sentry.captureException is able to run.

Answer (score 0):

Close Sentry connection before exit like this:

```
const Sentry = require('@sentry/node');
Sentry.init({ dsn: 'https://c3f5****************34dbf@sentry.io/1288850'});
try{
    throw new Error('test-error');
}
catch(e){
    const Eid = Sentry.captureException(e);
    console.log(Eid);
}
Sentry.close().then(() => process.exit(0));
```

Now all the pending Sentry logs will be reported before exit.